# Woocommerce - how to extend admin orders search to additional tables

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

It seems that WooCommerce admin order search is only able to search in order's meta fields (`wp_postmeta` table). The fields can even be customized by a filter. But how can I extend that search to also search other tables. In my case, I would like to search in order's comments which are stored in `post_excerpt` field (`wp_posts` table).

Tried to make use of `search_orders` function in `class-wc-order-data-store-cpt.php` but it seems it only searches within the orders found by the original meta fields search